# Google Maps API for queries, not rendering

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, maps

Is there a way to go through the process of creating a google map without all the rendering stuff? I have a project in which I need to do some spacial queries on a map, and I'm using the Maps API for it, but I don't actually have to display the map.

I know I could obviously just do `display: none`, but if it's possible, I'd like a solution that doesn't waste a bunch of client processing power to draw all of the map stuff in the first place, whether it actually gets rendered or not.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what type of spatial queries you're doing? Google Maps API primary purpose is to display a map, although it does have services (Directions, etc) to do other things. Depending on what you want to do, we may be able to suggest a better alternative.

Comment: @Gady I'm plotting a bunch of polygons that represent custom geographical areas, and I'm testing for the existence of a user-defined lat/long coordinate in each of them. So really `containsLocation` is the only one I'm using.

Comment: And you don't need a map when displaying the polygons?

Comment: @Gady I'm not displaying them. Each of the polygons represents a zone, and each zone has some values associated with it. I'm testing to see which zone a particular point is in, and then getting the associated values

Comment: What is your datastore, more specifically, where are the polygons stored?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently that is not allowed by the [Google Maps/Google Earth APIs Terms of Service, section 10.1 g)](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_1)

Quote:

> (g) No Use of Content without a Google Map. You must not use or display the Content without a corresponding Google map, unless you are explicitly permitted to do so in the Maps APIs Documentation, or through written permission from Google.